# Can't input a value to a JS variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I started learning JavaScript today, and to test it I made a page that changes the image shown when I click on a div. Everything was working fine, but I wanted to know how I could add an input element to specify how many steps I want to jump every time I click the button. I came up with an idea, however it isn't working. Seems like the variable is kind of "accumulating" values when I console.log it. I will link the codes, first one works and the second one doesn't. The first ones uses fixed values, and the square changes colors as it should be doing (the images don't really matter). The second one should jump steps: typing 1 would make it the same as the first one, typing 2 would make it jump one color.

https://jsfiddle.net/u2s3pqxL/1/

```
window.onload = function(){
        var x = 0;
        document.getElementById("teste").onclick = function(){myFunction()};
        function myFunction(){
            if (x == 0){
                document.getElementById("teste").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                document.getElementById("taiga").style.opacity = 1;
                document.getElementById("nanachi").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("azami").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("kcalb").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("moge-ko").style.opacity = 0;
                x += document.getElementById("number").value;
            } else if (x == 1){
                document.getElementById("teste").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                document.getElementById("taiga").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("nanachi").style.opacity = 1;
                document.getElementById("azami").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("kcalb").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("moge-ko").style.opacity = 0;
                x += document.getElementById("number").value;
            } else if (x == 2){
                document.getElementById("teste").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                document.getElementById("taiga").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("nanachi").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("azami").style.opacity = 1;
                document.getElementById("kcalb").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("moge-ko").style.opacity = 0;
                x += document.getElementById("number").value;
            } else if (x == 3){
                document.getElementById("teste").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
                document.getElementById("taiga").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("nanachi").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("azami").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("kcalb").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("moge-ko").style.opacity = 1;
                x += document.getElementById("number").value;
            } else if (x == 4){
                document.getElementById("teste").style.backgroundColor = "black";
                document.getElementById("taiga").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("nanachi").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("azami").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("kcalb").style.opacity = 1;
                document.getElementById("moge-ko").style.opacity = 0;
                x = 0;
            }
            console.log(x);
        };
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c3s1opb7/7/

```
window.onload = function(){
        var x = 0;
        document.getElementById("teste").onclick = function(){myFunction()};
        function myFunction(){
            if (x == 0){
                document.getElementById("teste").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                document.getElementById("taiga").style.opacity = 1;
                document.getElementById("nanachi").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("azami").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("kcalb").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("moge-ko").style.opacity = 0;
                x += 1;
            } else if (x == 1){
                document.getElementById("teste").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                document.getElementById("taiga").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("nanachi").style.opacity = 1;
                document.getElementById("azami").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("kcalb").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("moge-ko").style.opacity = 0;
                x += 1;
            } else if (x == 2){
                document.getElementById("teste").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                document.getElementById("taiga").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("nanachi").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("azami").style.opacity = 1;
                document.getElementById("kcalb").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("moge-ko").style.opacity = 0;
                x += 1;
            } else if (x == 3){
                document.getElementById("teste").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
                document.getElementById("taiga").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("nanachi").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("azami").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("kcalb").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("moge-ko").style.opacity = 1;
                x += 1;
            } else if (x >= 4){
                document.getElementById("teste").style.backgroundColor = "black";
                document.getElementById("taiga").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("nanachi").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("azami").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("kcalb").style.opacity = 1;
                document.getElementById("moge-ko").style.opacity = 0;
                x = 0;
            }
            console.log(x);
        };
    };
```

What should I do to make the second one work?

Comment: I don't really understand what's the problem... I've tested both of your codes, and (I think) they work correctly.

Comment: Oh... That's weird. It wasn't working before. But still, isn't working as intended. When I insert 1, it skips yellow and purple for some reason.

Comment: input value is a string. console.log(x) would show you your issue.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I am confused because it is "kind of" working. How do I make it an actual number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have:

```
x += document.getElementById("number").value;
```

with this, you asked in your var "x" to add the value of your input.. with type String...
For example, you have the value "1" in the input and 0 in your varaible "x"..
If you follow your code, the result after this expression:

```
x += document.getElementById("number").value;
```

Your result will be: 01
and you, you want: 1

because you add a type String in your variable type Integer..

You must parse the varaible in Integer with this parseInt():

```
x += parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
```